# How to create wordpress page that lets users create their own quiz?

Tags: plugins, pages

I am new to wordpress and I want to create a page that lets the user create their own quiz. Is there any existing plugin for that purpose? For eg. take a look at this: https://en.vonvon.me/quiz/940?utm_viral=28

Comment: Welcome to WordPress! [This site is meant for developer questions.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) You would be better served asking your question on the [WordPress.org support forums](https://wordpress.org/support/).

Answer (score 1):

Since you are new to WordPress, I suggest you to do some study on basic stuffs on posts, types of posts and queries related core functions. It will be quite useful for you.

And, to maintain the profiles of users, you may go for **BuddyPress** plugin. Later on, you may work-out on the custom post types with buddypress and achieve the quiz functionality you want to.

For custom post types, either create it manually through functions.php for which you need to study post_types and WP core functions. An alternate for the same could be a CPT (Custom Post Type) plugin. You may checkout their respective documentation files on how to use them.